# How to make a function that receives a pointer to the number that will be multiplied and divide by two?

Tags: c, function, division, bit-shift, multiplication

I know I can do it by bit shift to the left for multiplication and to the right for division, but the thing that confuse me is the parameter of the function (pointer) to the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
void func(unsigned *u)
{
   *u >>= 1;        // do the operation on the unsigned value pointed by u.
                    // u contains the address of the object (in this case, the unsigned)
}
```

and call

```
unsigned a = 23;
func(&a);    // pass the pointer to the variable a. After the function executes,
             // a will be changed as the operation is done on it.
```